# Backpack Contents in Text Adventure

Tags: javascript, text, adventure

I'm currently making a text adventure. I'm implementing a feature where if you have a certain item, you can trade it for a hint in the game. I'm just having trouble figuring out how to search the backpack for the item so that the correct hint will show itself.

Here are the statements:

```
case "drift wood":
case "soda can":
    case "shell":
        case "fork":
if(mapLocation === 9)
{
    gameMessage = "Weren't there some loose planks in that sunken ship?";

    backpack.splice(backpackIndexNumber, 1);
}
else if(mapLocation === 9)
{
    gameMessage = "That trench sure was dark.";

    backpack.splice(backpackIndexNumber, 1);
}
else if(mapLocation === 9)
{
    gameMessage = "That loose sand on the beach sure looks like fun to dig into.";
    backpack.splice(backpackIndexNumber, 1);
}
else if(mapLocation === 9)
{
    gameMessage = "A treasure chest needs unlocking.";
    backpack.splice(backpackIndexNumber, 1);
}
break;
```

For the first if(mapLocation === 9), I need the program to search the backpack for the crowbar in order to get the "Weren't there some loose planks in that sunken ship?" message.

My backpack variable is this:

```
var backpack = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

If your backpack array simply contains the string "crowbar", then you do it like this:

```
hasCrowbar = backpack.indexOf("crowbar") > -1;
```

If, on the otherhand, your backpack contains an object like this:

```
var backpackObj = [ 
    {
      item: "thing1",
      weight: 10
    }, 
    {
      item: "crowbar",
      weight: 20
    }
  ];
```

Then I'd use lodash, and check it like this:

```
hasCrowbarObj = _.filter(backpackObj, function(b){
  return b.item === "crowbar";
}).length > 0;
```

Here's a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/uf74d9sb/1/